# BindingContext not working for navigation in a button clicked event

Tags: xamarin, binding

I am attempting to navigate to a registration page from a login page using a button_clicked event. A new view model is created during the event and set as the BindingContext. However it does not appear to work

When I debug on the registration page I have an ICommand in the registration  page view model that is attached to a button. The code is

```
    public ICommand RegisterAppUser
    {
        get
        {
                return new RelayCommand(RegisterUser,  () => Email == ConfirmEmail && Password == ConfirmPassword);

        }
    }

    private async void RegisterUser()
    {

        var userDto = new RegistrationUserDto(this);
        App.User = await App.PlayerManager.RegisterUserAsync(userDto);
    }
```

I assumed the the "this" would represent the view model attached to the view. However when I reach the RegistrationUserDto(this) line I can see that the "this" is an unintialized instance of the registration view model

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new RegistrationView() { BindingContext = new RegistrationViewModel() }); ; 
    }
}
```

No compilation errors but the action clearly can't work with no data

Comment: Your question is vague can you give me a gist of the issue?

Comment: Do you have a try with setting `BindingContext = new RegistrationViewModel()` in `RegisterUser()` method ?